# What local Ip-Address should i use to connect to the local web service on my pc to test apk on arc welder?

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

I have been using the [arc welder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn) chrome extension to test my android app.And i am having trouble to connect to the local web service. What ip address should i use?I have tried emulator's local ip address 10.0.2.2 as well as also tried the 127.0.0.1.Can any one help me please?